# Why does this return no method error when trying ordering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called `acts_as_follower`(https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

Here, I'm trying to fetch all the users who are following current_user.

then I want them ordered by the column called `last_active_at`

So I tried to code like this but it returned error. 
How can I fix?

**controller**

```
@followed_users = current_user.followers.order('users.last_active_at DESC').limit(10)
```

**Error Message**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x0000000ab3cf18>):
```

Comment: Please update the question with model code.

Comment: @ManojMonga Or could you please just tell me how to fetch record ordered by DESC? with this code `@followed_users = current_user.followers.sort_by{ |n| n.last_active_at }.take(10)`

Comment: See, `current_user.followers` is what fetching the followers here in an array. And according to a comment on my answer, it is giving error. Anyways if this is working for you, still you can't tweak it to just fetch 10 records as this query is being handled by gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you can try this

ASC:
`current_user.followers.sort!{ |a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }.take(10)`
 DESC:
`current_user.followers.sort!{ |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }.take(10)`

Answer (score 2):

`followers` method return `Array`
and `Array` do not have any `order` method in ruby

Please look
From [github](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower):--

"book.followers  # Returns an array of all the followers for that book, a collection of different object types (eg. type User or type Book)"

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any potential way to solve this?

Comment: Thanks I did! your comment worked but one more thing!! Can you make it change to DESC order instead of ASC??

Comment: ASC:   current_user.followers.sort!{ |a,b| a <=>b }.take(10)    DESC:  current_user.followers.sort!{ |a,b| b <=>a }.take(10)

Comment: When I want it sorted by `last_active_at` Is this fine? @followed_users = current_user.followers.sort{ |a,b| a <=>b }.sort_by{ |n| n.last_active_at }.take(10)

Comment: ASC:   current_user.followers.sort!{ |a,b| a.last_activate_at <=> b.last_activate_at }.take(10)    DESC:  current_user.followers.sort!{ |a,b| b.last_activate_at <=> a.last_activate_at }.take(10)

Comment: Thanks I tried DESC but it returned this error `NoMethodError (undefined method `last_activate_at' for #<User:0x000000022e74b0>):
`

Comment: do you have that column on users table if not then please do ASC: current_user.followers.sort!{ |a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }.take(10) DESC: current_user.followers.sort!{ |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }.take(10)

Comment: @followed_users = current_user.followers.sort_by{ |n| n.last_active_at }.reverse.take(10) for descending order.

Comment: @RajaD Can you please tell me why should reverse not be used here?

Comment: Yes reverse is reversing your array whatever it is so it is not a good coding

Comment: @RajaD Thanks it worked perfect!! Is it supposed be bad practice to do so though? could make a new answer so that I can make it as a best answer?

Comment: sure you just tick the right button for accepting my answer @MKK Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Arrays dont have any `order` method. You could do something like this

```
@followed_users = current_user.followers.sort_by{ |n| n.last_active_at }
```

Then when displaying in the view you can limit it to how many ever you want or do it from the controller (suggested way).

Comment: @followed_users = current_user.followers.sort_by{ |n| n.last_active_at }.take(10)  thanks

Comment: Thanks! but it's ASC. Can you change it to DESC??

Comment: What if there are 1000 (for example, there can be more in real scenarios) followers. It will fetch them all from database unnecessarily.

Comment: Its gonna run the query anyways, i would go with what @RajaD added to the solution. Apart from that if you very concerned about the database fetch results and overloading then I would say defining a custom method inside your controller is a good idea depending on may params or conditions and then according display in the views.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [readme@github](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) followers takes an optional hash parameter of ActiveRecord options (:limit, :order, etc…)

So this should work:

```
@followed_users = current_user.followers(:order => 'users.last_active_at DESC', :limit => 10)
```

Comment: It returned this error `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError (Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :follower):`